# UIImagePicker Jumping Back To Portrait When Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a bit of a strange situation. I have a photo app that automatically sets the app orientation based upon the dimensions of the image loaded. I use the following code.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
return NO;
}

- (IBAction)setRotation {

if(imageOriginal.size.height > imageOriginal.size.width){

    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

}else {

    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

}

}
```

The problem is that lets say I load a portrait image into the app the UIImagePicker is in portrait mode. I now select a Landscape image and select the UIImagePicker again, instead of the picker now being in landscape mode it jumps back to portrait and looks pretty ugly.

Is there a better way to set the device orientation based upon the image or fix the problem above?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution needed to change the following code to make sure the UIImagePicker was in context.

```
- (IBAction)loadImage:(id)sender {

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
-- > imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
//imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```